# ¿Como hacer que mi status solo actualice las fechas vencidas?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, ajax

Necesito que mi estado se actualice dependiendo a la fecha que tomo del sistema comparándola con la fecha limite y mi código actualiza absolutamente todo a vencido, como si no tomara en cuenta la comparación de la fecha de hoy y la fecha de limite.
Si aun no llega la fecha en la que se paga debe mostrar pendiente

```
                            <?php
                            foreach ($calen as $cal) {
                                $alumno = $cal->getAlumn();
                                $sql = "select start_at from calendar";
                                $sql_2 = "select status from calendar";
                                $fecha = $sql; //fecha obtenible de sql
                                $estat = $sql_2; //status
                                $hoy = date('d-m-Y'); //fecha de hoy
                                Executor::doit($sql);

                                if ($fecha<=$hoy) {     //FALSE
                                    $lbl_status = "Pendiente";
                                    $lbl_class = 'label bg-primary';
                                    $stat=1;
                                } 
                                if ($fecha>$hoy) { //TRUE
                                    $lbl_status = "Vencido";
                                    $lbl_class = 'label bg-red';
                                    $stat=2;
                                }
                                $sql_1 = "UPDATE calendar SET status= $stat";
                                Executor::doit($sql_1);
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $alumno->code; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $alumno->name . " " . $alumno->lastname; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $cal->start_at; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="<?php echo $lbl_class; ?>"><?php echo $lbl_status; ?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        <?php
```

Comment: Actualiza todos los registros, porque tu update no tiene una cláusula `where`, así que le va a poner el valor de `$stat` a todos los registros que existan. Sospecho que tus otras sentencias `select` también necesitan un `where`, pero eres tu el que sabe qué está intentando.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de tener la lógica en php, hay que dejarla en SQL y agregar un WHERE.

```
UPDATE calendar SET status = 2 WHERE start_at > CURDATE();
```

Con esa sencilla instrucción ahorras mucho código que no entiendo que tanto hace ahí aparte de consumir recursos.

Comment: ok, lo entiendo pero en php necesito mostrar las etiquetas de color dependiendo si esta vencido o pendiente asi que lo que necesito también es saber la solución lógica en php @LuisCazares

Comment: Tu pregunta fue porque se actualizaban todos. y esta es la respuesta a esa pregunta. Lo otro, que vos queres, no esta ni en tu pregunta ni explicado en ningun lado. Asi que acepta esta respuesta (que es correcta) y si tenes otra pregunta distinta, hacela...